# Java Library System Program - saving program

Tags: java, class, csv, save, edit

I am trying to save my data from my program to a file but it will not save added books or students. The program will run but it will not save any data and will not allow the program to save the data.

```java
    private static void addBook() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int isbn, numbercopies;
        String title, author, publisher;


        System.out.println("\nEnter Title: ");
        title = in.next();

        System.out.println("\nEnter Author: ");
        author = in.next();

        System.out.println("\nEnter Publisher: ");
        publisher = in.next();

        System.out.println("\nEnter ISBN: ");
        isbn = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\nEnter Number of Copies:");
        numbercopies = in.nextInt();


// creating book object

        Book b = new Book(isbn, numbercopies, title, author, publisher);

// adding book to library via method

        lib.addBook(b);
    }

    private static void addStudent(){

        int sID, age;
        String FirstName, LastName;




        System.out.println("\nEnter Full Name: ");
        LastName = in.nextLine();
        FirstName = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nEnter Age: ");
        age = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("\nEnter Student ID:");
        sID = in.nextInt();

        Students s = new Students(age, sID, FirstName, LastName);

// adding student to student library

        slib.addStudent(s);

    }

// method to save and quit  


    private static void saveAndQuit() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Enter file name for Student: ");
        fileName = in.next();

// stop the program from running with the boolean, through break        
        running = false;

// writing to file      
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;


        try {

            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(slib);



//closing the stream            
            fos.close();
            out.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


// getting the file input

    private static void loadScript(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream in = null;
        File file = new File(name);
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                lib = (Library) in.readObject();
                fis.close();
                in.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("\nThe file does not exist!");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Normally on a forum like Stackoverflow members gives solutions for problems that a coder is experiencing. A Good post is to post what you have tried and where your error is. For example "deleting a book" code and what part seems to be failing. This will help members to help you as quick as possible. Also members  see postings like this as someone that did not try and want statckoverflow users to write the code for them. Post your delete or save code and what you have tried. Not the whole program it makes it difficult to help.  Members need to see that you did do your research.

Comment: sorry for that i have edited the post

Comment: Does it go into the catch? Does it create any file or is the file blank?

Comment: No file is created

Comment: Going to try and help going to post an awnser

Answer (score 0):

Did not see if the class that you are writing to file was implement serialized.

If it was check this link also notice the Java version you are using. For now hardcode the file path and name just to see if its working.

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/

Also put in some logging or console prints just to see where the code goes.

Comment: Ill try this and see if it works but i think there is something wrong with my save method

Comment: Just make sure the object "slib" is serialized or implements Serializable.